# Question related to another question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I ask a question, some guys answer, and another question comes in. Though the later question is related to previous one, the topic is different, I mean it should be tagged with some different tags
It this case what should I do? Ask in comments, editing my question and ask new question at the rest of previous one, or open another question with a link to previous one? If latter, should I link older question to newly asked one, too?

Comment: An excellently formulated problem in a perfectly separated and distilled manner. This may even make it to be a FAQ eventually. I already see myself linking here in response to [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Should I change my question after I have received answers?

Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received.

It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered (if they now look wrong they may attract downvotes)

If you have a related or additional question to the original then create a new question. You can link back to the original for reference.

Comment: And what if want to ask that question from the guy who answered the previous one? should I comment link to the new question in a comment and ask them to visit the new question?

Comment: No. You shouldn't @ping people asking them to look at different questions.

Comment: "And what if want to ask that question from the guy who answered the previous one?" If you want any kind of control over this, then you are looking for a discussion forum. Stack Overflow is not one of those.